# Missing namespace Phone when trying to create an app bar

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm starting with Windows Phone development.

I'm trying to follow [this Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431786(v=vs.105).aspx) in order to create an app bar in my page. But in the first step when I add the line

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
```

the compiler complains

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Phone' does not exist 
            in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I created my project using Visual Studio 2013 community and the **Blank App (Windows Phone)** template.

I have checked and with the **Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight)** template this does not happen but I read in other posts that silverlight is an older system so I suppoused I have not to use it

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An App for Windows Phone RT must utilize the other [AppBar class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.aspx).

Please investigate the following article [Quickstart: adding app bars (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781232.aspx) to get more information about modern app bars.

Answer (score 1):

As in the msdn article itself, it says that it only supports for `WP8` & 8.1 version of  `WPSilverlight`. What's the app you created?

Normally `Blank App` would create a `Runtime` WP application(the normal XAML not the `Silverlight`), version of 8.1 which ideally won't support the namespace you mentioned above.